# How to read data of type stream from in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, stream

I am consuming api which have a data of stream type and I want to access that and get chunks and display till the request completes. How would I be able to do that as I am getting following attributes in response

[image]

htmlStream here is the attribute of type stream.

[enter image description here][2]

Api Response :
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eukvI.png

Comment: We're gonna need more details. What does `htmlStream` look like? Is the response a JSON?

Comment: @yuriy636 api response added you can check